# Rails 6 create new route for endpoint with two params in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a daily basis I use GrapeAPI to create API. Because I don't want to rust I'm trying to create app using Rails::API (ActionController::API). The thing is I want to have endpoint to be like:

`GET products/:product_id/shipment/:id` - which retrieve data on a specific shipment. How to create routes for such action?

`ShipmentController`

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product

  def show
    @shipment = Shipment.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called nested routes which you can define like so:

```
resources :products do
  resources :shipments
end
```

However, there is a concept called **shallow nesting**, which means you only created nested routes for the `new` and the `create` method. The reason is, only for those two actions you don't have a record in the DB yet, and you need the id of the associated model (products) which you get though the id in the params.
Once you have your shipment record in the DB, you can just access it in a non-nested way through its ID. (The associated record - the nested parent if you will in your case the products - will be accessible through the record itself).
Shallow nested routes:

```
resources :products do
  resources :shipments, only: [:new, :create]
end
resources :shipments, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Answer (score 0):

```rb
resources :products do
  resources :shipments
end
```

This will nest the routes, allowing you to find your product by `:product_id` and that product's shipment by the `:id`